# IdentityServer3: Local Database + Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I use at the moment IdentityServer3 in combination with AspNetIdentity. Now I want to expand the authentication to the active directory. For this I want to create a checkbox on the logon screen, where the user could decide if he wants to authenticate aigainst to active directory or to the local database:

[image]

Now my questions are:

1. I require in my custom user service the information, if the checkbox for windows authentication is checked. Then I could write the following code:

   ```
   public async override Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
   {
           // check if the option for windows authentication is set
           // Yes: Authenticate over active directory: UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, username)
           // No: Authenticate over local database 
   }
   ```
2. Is this a good approach to solve my requirements or is there a better solution? I want to design it so simple as possible for the user.

Thank you for helping!!

Comment: This generally will not work, because you need to do a 401 handshake, and you haven't done that at the point of authentication. Have you considered setting up the Windows authentication as another identity provider? It may be a little bit more extensible for your future scenarios (e.g. when your identityserver is no longer hosted in AD for example).

Comment: I have the following szenario: I have a Angular App, which redirects the user to the Identity Server. Then the user see the login page (username/password) - The user should decide if he want to authenticate against the local database or the active directory. If I set up a second identityServer for windows authentication, it will be very complicated for the user, because I must redirect him to another login site

Comment: You can load another identity provider inside your existing IdentityServer3 alongside your username/password authentication. If people want to use Windows auth, they click on that. That'll redirect the user to another IdentityProvider under the water which has access to Windows auth, and will generate a token as you are used to. User will not see anything form that. See https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth) and https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth%20All-in-One)

Comment: At the moment I implement the following solution: In the AuthenticateLocalAsync method I check, if the user is available in the local database. If the user **is** in the local database, I validate username and password against the **local database**. If the user **is not** in the local database, I validate username and password against the **active directory**